# are all k-hyperperfect numbers for k>1 odd

Tags: number-theory

a number is k-hyperfect if it satisfies (sigma(n)-n-1)(k)+1=n for some positive integer k. For example, 301 is 6-hyperperfect because (sigma(301)-301-1)(6)+1=301. all perfect numbers are 1-hyperperfect. It appears that all hyperperfect numbers for all k>1 are odd. i verified this for the first 10000 terms in https://oeis.org/A034897. is there a way to prove this or are some hyperperfect numbers even for k>1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all $k$-hyperperfect numbers for $k>1$ are odd.

---

Suppose $k>1$ and $n$ is an even number.

- $n=2$. $\ (\sigma(n)-n-1)k + 1 = 0k+1=1 < n$.
- Otherwise, $n>2$. $\ n/2$ is a proper factor of $n$.
  $$(\sigma(n)-n-1)k + 1 \ge \frac n2k+1\ge n + 1\gt n$$

So, $n$ is not a $k$-perfect number.

---

**Exercise**. Show that all factors of a $k$-perfect number except $1$ must be great than $k$.